# product/add of dynamically added inputs not working jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a form, it is product of values in first row well

I have a form dynamically add input values. Here first row input qty*product = total is working fine, But next added element saving total of first input and passing to all next element. 
    Here I want of get all individual of qty * product = total and calculate all total number of input values

Here is my working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/jvk3/595hek8y/3/

Here is my jquery script

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var total_input = 1;
        var temp_arr = [];  

        function calculateFinal(){
            var final_val = 0;
            $('.total').each(function(){
                final_val += parseFloat($(this).val());                                    
            });
            $('#final_total').val(final_val);            
        }

        jQuery(document).ready(function($){

            temp_arr[0] = total_input;
            $('.my-form .add-box').click(function(){
                var n = $('.text-box').length + 1;
                if( 10 < n ) {
                    alert('Stop it!');
                    return false;
                }
                ++total_input;
                temp_arr.push(total_input);
                var box_html = $('<p class="text-box"> <input type="text" name="size['+total_input+']"  class="add" value="" id="box1' + total_input + '" /> <input type="text" name="qty['+total_input+']" class="add" value="" id="box2' + total_input + '" /> Sub-Total: <input name="sum['+total_input+']" class="total" value=""/> <a href="#" rel="'+total_input+'" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>');
                jQuery('#my-form').append(box_html);
                box_html.hide();
                $('.my-form p.text-box:last').after(box_html);
                box_html.fadeIn('slow');
                return false;
            });

            $('.my-form').on('click', '.remove-box', function(){
                var this_rel = $(this).attr('rel');
                $(this).parent().css( 'background-color', '#FF6C6C' );
                $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    var len = temp_arr.length;
                    for(i=0;i<len;i++){  
                        if(temp_arr[i] == this_rel){
                            temp_arr.splice(i,1);                                 
                        }
                    }
                    $(this).remove();
                    calculateFinal();
                    $('.box-number').each(function(index){
                        $(this).text( index + 1 );
                    });
                });
                $('span.total').html( $('input.add').sumValues() );

                return false;
            });
        });

        $.fn.sumValues = function(i) {
            var sum = 0; 
            this.each(function() {
                if ( $(this).parent().find('input.add') ) {
                    var obj = $(this).parent().find('input.add');
                    if(obj.val()!='' || typeof obj != "undefined"){
                        var val = 0;
                        $(obj).each(function(){
                            val = parseFloat($("#box1").val()*$("#box2").val());  

                        });
                        sum += parseFloat( ('0' + val).replace(/[^0-9-\.]/g, ''), 10 ); 
                        $('input[name="sum['+i+']"]').val(sum);                        
                    }

                }


            });


            return sum;
        };

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).on('keyup','input.add', function() {
                var len = temp_arr.length;
                for(i=0;i<len;i++){  
                    $('input.total').html( $('input[name="sum['+temp_arr[i]+']"]').sumValues(temp_arr[i]) );
                    calculateFinal();
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update you keyup event:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input.add', function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.text-box');//get the parent
    var val = parseFloat(parent.find("input:eq(0)").val()) * parseFloat(parent.find("input:eq(1)").val());//calculate using the parent inputs

    $(this).closest('.text-box').find('.total').val(val);//append to the parent total
    calculateFinal();//caculate the total
  });
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/gzx5vx59/

for the NaN you can drop some default values in the forms or do some validations

https://jsfiddle.net/gzx5vx59/1/

Comment: you need to calculate the total for each line, the previous code was searching for the inputs based on ids with will only take the first inputs with those ids, my code takes the inputs based on the parent .text-box element so the total is calculated for each line correctly